# How to press Ctrl + Alt + Ñ?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, adobe-photoshop, shortcuts, hotkeys

I am using Photoshop CS6 Extended in Windows 10. In the top menu under *View* there is a *Lock Guides* option. The shortcut keyboard combination for this is mentioned as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ñ</kbd>. I tried everything like Num Lock and Caps Lock, but I couldn't find how to press Ñ.

How to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ñ</kbd>?

Thanx.

Comment: This might actually be a broken shortcut. Have you tried changing it? Right now I can't think of any keyboard layout I know that has **Ñ** on there without requiring a modifier key. If you have the modifier, you might just have to use that while holding down **Ctrl+Alt** and then continue pressing **N**.

Comment: @Mario No, I didn't change nothing. It is the default shortcut keyboard combination. I don't know about any modifier key on keyboard too.

Comment: In my Photoshop CS6 (Windows 10), the default shortcut for Lock Guides seems to be Ctrl+Alt+Semicolon. Perhaps give that a try.

Comment: @MJH I am using the extended version. In this it is written Ctrl+Alt+Ñ not semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

It should be Alt+Ctrl+;

Thats what works with the US / EN-US language settings, I think youre running spanish version of it?

Comment: The language of photoshop I am using is English not spanish. It says version 13.0 x32 Extended.

Comment: @user31782 - What keyboard layout are you using though?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know what it's layout is called. It is [DELL KB216 Wired Multimedia USB Keyboard](http://www.amazon.in/DELL-KB216-Wired-Multimedia-Keyboard/dp/B00ZYLMQH0/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1481901555&sr=1-1&keywords=dell+keyboard) in India.

Comment: Please update your question and list the keyboard layouts you have installed.